# How to plot response of a non-linear state space model in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, non-linear, state-space

I am trying to plot a non-linear model in order to compare it with it's linearized counterpart.

I am following this paper [Nonlinear Model & Controller Design for Magnetic Levitation System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d25a/42958aa11bbd30171a8e496f412a45d22b1f.pdf) and trying to reproduce the results the authors obtained. In particular I am trying to plot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above equations can be represented in vector format as follows:

[image]

I found no references on how to plot non linear state space model representations on MathWorks.

The Simulink [state-space block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html) is used to implement linear state-space systems and not non linear ones.

So, **how can I plot the response of a non-linear state space model in Simulink ?** Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use a [`Matlab Function Block`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html) to implement the nonlinear equations. You can define the inputs and outputs yourself in this block.

The body of the function block will look something like this:

```
function [xdot, y] = nonlinearss(x,u)

    % define  constants
    g = 9.81
    % etc...

    % nonlinear set of equations
    xdot = [x(2); g-C/m*(x(3)/x(1))^2; etc...] + [0;0;1/L]*u;

    y = x.';
```